# Pandas: Extract data from column A that does not exist for column B

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

My data includes invoices and I have to check whether an invoice was already paid or not. 
For each invoice I loop through all report dates. If on one day, the invoice doen't show up, it means the customer already made a payment and of course it won't appear again on subsequent days.

You can see from the table below that invoice C was paid on 28/05.

```
Report Date  Invoice No
2019-05-28   D
2019-05-28   A
2019-05-28   B

2019-05-27   A
2019-05-27   B
2019-05-27   C

2019-05-26   A
2019-05-26   B
2019-05-26   C
```

I wrote the code below, it worked but took too long because there are around 800k entries. This is very inefficient. I wonder if there is a more efficient way to solve this using pandas.

```py
# For every Invoice
for i in range(0,len(documentNo.categories)):
    # If the invoice still exists in the newest Report Date (here 28/05), means that it has not been paid yet. So we can skip to check other invoices
    if (df.loc[(df['Document No'] == documentNo.categories[i]) & (df['Report Date'] == reportDates.categories[len(reportDates.categories) - 1])].all(1).any()):
        continue

    # Decrement from date 27/05
    for j in range(len(reportDates.categories) - 2,0,-1):

        # If the Invoice does not exist on this date, it has been paid
        if (df.loc[(df['Document No'] == documentNo.categories[i]) & (df['Report Date'] != reportDates.categories[j])].all(1).any()):
            break
```

As a result I want a new column which shows Open/Closed for each row.

```
Report Date  Invoice No  Open/Closed
2019-05-28   D           Open
2019-05-28   A           Open
2019-05-28   B           Open

2019-05-27   A           Open
2019-05-27   B           Open
2019-05-27   C           Closed

2019-05-26   A           Open
2019-05-26   B           Open
2019-05-26   C           Closed
```

Comment: have a look to `np.select`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is on way we using `crosstab`, then is the the invoice eq to 0 , which means the previous invoices should be count as `Closed`

```
s=pd.crosstab(df.ReportDate,df.InvoiceNo).eq(0)

Newdf=(s.iloc[::-1,:].cummax()&~s).replace({True:'Closed',False:'Open'}).stack().reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df)).reset_index()
Newdf
Out[342]: 
   ReportDate InvoiceNo       0
0  2019-05-28         D    Open
1  2019-05-28         A    Open
2  2019-05-28         B    Open
3  2019-05-27         A    Open
4  2019-05-27         B    Open
5  2019-05-27         C  Closed
6  2019-05-26         A    Open
7  2019-05-26         B    Open
8  2019-05-26         C  Closed
```

Comment: This code is the fastest! Im stunned how you guys solved that in just 2 lines. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [dummy](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) variables to get the presense of `InvoiceNo`, then do a sum as per the date and [stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) it.

Here, 0 means closed and 1 means open. You can easily [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) them with the `dict`

```
data = pd.concat([df,pd.get_dummies(df['InvoiceNo'])],1).drop('InvoiceNo',1).set_index('ReportDate')
r = data.groupby(data.index).sum()
r = (r.iloc[-1:].values | r) & r.iloc[-1:].values
res = r.stack().reset_index(name='Open/Closed').rename(columns={'level_1':'InvoiceNo'})
res['Open/Closed'] = res['Open/Closed'].map(map_dict={0:'Closed',1:'Open'})
res = df.merge(res, 'left')
```

Output:

```
  ReportDate InvoiceNo Open/Closed
0 2019-05-28         D        Open
1 2019-05-28         A        Open
2 2019-05-28         B        Open
3 2019-05-27         A        Open
4 2019-05-27         B        Open
5 2019-05-27         C      Closed
6 2019-05-26         A        Open
7 2019-05-26         B        Open
8 2019-05-26         C      Closed
```

Comment: thank you! I guess it works but it takes too much memory (i got a 'Memory Error')

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to access each dataframe grouped per `Invoice No` with [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and conditionally check with [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) if [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) of the dates are equal to the `max` date in our dataframe:

```
dfs = []

for _, d in df.groupby('Invoice No'):
    d['Open/Closed'] = np.where(d['Report Date'].eq(df['Report Date'].max()).any(), 'Open', 'Closed')
    dfs.append(d)

df2 = pd.concat(dfs).sort_values('Report Date', ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
  Report Date Invoice No Open/Closed
0  2019-05-28          A        Open
1  2019-05-28          B        Open
2  2019-05-28          D        Open
3  2019-05-27          A        Open
4  2019-05-27          B        Open
5  2019-05-27          C      Closed
6  2019-05-26          A        Open
7  2019-05-26          B        Open
8  2019-05-26          C      Closed
```